# Changing ScriptProcessor to AudioWorklet but seems quite slow

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to streaming audio to server for Speech to text.
the script is working, but the only problem is that `ScriptProcessor has been depreciated`. and I heard Firefox does not support it anymore. 
so, I'm trying to convert `ScriptProcessor`  to `AudioWorklet` .

this is the previous client.js which has `ScriptProcessor`

```
var app = {
    socket:  null,
    mediaTrack: null,
    counter: 0,
    bufferSize: 4096,
    main: function() {
      this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80");
      this.socket.addEventListener("open", this.onSocketOpen.bind(this));
      this.socket.addEventListener("message", this.onSocketMessage.bind(this));
    },
    onSocketOpen: function(event) {
      this.initRecorder();
      console.log("onSocketOpen", event);
    },
    onSocketMessage: function(event) {
      console.log("Message", event.data);
        document.getElementById("transcript").innerHTML += "<p>" + event.data + "</p>"
    },
    shimAudioContext: function() {
      try {
        // Shims
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
      } catch (e) {
        alert("Your browser is not supported");
        return false;
      }

      if(!navigator.getUserMedia || !window.AudioContext) {
        alert("Your browser is not supported");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    initRecorder: function() {
      // shim audio context
      if (!this.shimAudioContext()) {
        return;
      }

      return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({"audio": true, "video": false}).then((stream) => {
        var context = new window.AudioContext();

        // send metadata on audio stream to backend
        this.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
          rate: context.sampleRate,
          language: "ja-JP",
          format: "LINEAR16"
        }));

        // Caputure mic audio data into a stream
        var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        // only record mono audio w/a buffer of 2048 bits per function call
        var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(this.bufferSize, 1, 1);

        // specify the processing function
        recorder.onaudioprocess = this.audioProcess.bind(this);

        // connect stream to our recorder
        audioInput.connect(recorder);

        // connect recorder to previous destination
        recorder.connect(context.destination);

        // store media track
        this.mediaTrack = stream.getTracks()[0];
      });
    },
    float32To16BitPCM: function(float32Arr) {
      var pcm16bit = new Int16Array(float32Arr.length);
      for(var i = 0; i < float32Arr.length; ++i) {

        // force number in [-1,1]
        var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, float32Arr[i]));

        /**
         * convert 32 bit float to 16 bit int pcm audio
         * 0x8000 = minimum int16 value, 0x7fff = maximum int16 value
         */
        pcm16bit[i] = s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF;
      }
      return pcm16bit;
    },
    audioProcess: function(event) {
      // only 1 channel as specified above.....
      var float32Audio = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0) || new Flaot32Array(this.bufferSize);
      var pcm16Audio = this.float32To16BitPCM(float32Audio);
      this.socket.send(pcm16Audio.buffer);
    }
  };
  app.main();
```

and this is new client.js which works with pricessor.js

```
var app = {
  socket: null,
  mediaTrack: null,
  counter: 0,
  bufferSize: 4096,
  main: function() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80");
    this.socket.addEventListener("open", this.onSocketOpen.bind(this));
    this.socket.addEventListener("message", this.onSocketMessage.bind(this));
  },
  onSocketOpen: function(event) {
    this.initRecorder();
    console.log("onSocketOpen", event);
  },
  onSocketMessage: function(event) {
    console.log("Message", event.data);
    document.getElementById("transcript").innerHTML += "<p>" + event.data + "</p>"
  },
  shimAudioContext: function() {
    try {
      // Shims
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
          navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
          navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Your browser is not supported");
      return false;
    }

    if(!navigator.getUserMedia || !window.AudioContext) {
      alert("Your browser is not supported");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  initRecorder: function() {
    // shim audio context
    if (!this.shimAudioContext()) {
      return;
    }

    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({"audio": true, "video": false}).then((stream) => {
      var context = new window.AudioContext();

      // send metadata on audio stream to backend
      this.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        rate: context.sampleRate,
        language: "ja-JP",
        format: "LINEAR16"
      }));

      // Capture mic audio data into a stream
      var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

      // add the custom audioWorklet processor
      return context.audioWorklet.addModule('/static/processor.js').then(() => {
        var recorder = new AudioWorkletNode(context, 'my-processor');
      
        // listen to messages from the processor
        recorder.port.onmessage = (event) => {
          // convert the buffer back to a typed array
          var pcm16Audio = new Int16Array(event.data);
          this.socket.send(pcm16Audio);
        };

        // connect stream to our recorder
        audioInput.connect(recorder);
  
        // connect recorder to previous destination
        recorder.connect(context.destination);
  
        // store media track
        this.mediaTrack = stream.getTracks()[0];
      });
    });
  },
};
app.main();
```

processor.js

```
class MyProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    const input = inputs[0];
    const pcm16Audio = this.float32To16BitPCM(input[0]);
    this.port.postMessage(pcm16Audio.buffer);
    return true;
  }

  float32To16BitPCM(float32Arr) {
    var pcm16bit = new Int16Array(float32Arr.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < float32Arr.length; ++i) {
      // force number in [-1,1]
      var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, float32Arr[i]));
      // convert 32 bit float to 16 bit int pcm audio
      pcm16bit[i] = s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF;
    }
    return pcm16bit;
  }
}

registerProcessor('my-processor', MyProcessor);
```

the conversion is kinda working. it seems sending audio data to server for speech to text. However, seems the speed is way slower than the old client.js. and after the conversion, I got an error, `Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time."}"`

this is the server.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import io
import threading
import queue


# from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.gapic.speech.v1 import speech_client
from google.cloud.proto.speech.v1 import cloud_speech_pb2
# from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
import os
# Set the environment variable for authentication
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './sample.json'


class StreamingRequest(object):
  """A Streaming Request iterable for speech api."""

  def __init__(self, audio_stream, config):
    """Initializes the streaming request obj.
    params:
    audio_stream: An AudioStream obj
    config: The protobuf configuration for api call
    """
    self.audio_stream = audio_stream
    self.config = config
    self.is_first = True

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    return self.next()

  def next(self):
    """Generate the next gRPC streaming api request."""
    if self.audio_stream.closed:
      return None

    if self.is_first:
      self.is_first = False
      return cloud_speech_pb2.StreamingRecognizeRequest(
              streaming_config=self.config)

    # block until read some data or until stream closed
    data = self.audio_stream.read()
    while not self.audio_stream.closed and len(data) == 0:
      data = self.audio_stream.read()

    return cloud_speech_pb2.StreamingRecognizeRequest(
            audio_content=data)


def results_to_dict(results):
  if results is None:
    return []

  output = []
  for result in results.results:
    r = {}
    r["stability"] = result.stability
    r["is_final"] = False
    if result.is_final:
      r["is_final"] = True

    r["alternatives"] = []
    for alternative in result.alternatives:
      r["alternatives"].append({
          "transcript": alternative.transcript,
          "confidence": alternative.confidence,
      })
    output.append(r)
  return output

class AudioStream(io.BytesIO):
  """Read dumps latest unread written data."""

  def read(self, n=None):
    """Reads up to `n` bytes."""
    if not hasattr(self, "_position"):
        self._position = 0

    self.seek(self._position)
    data = super(AudioStream, self).read(n)
    self._position += len(data)
    return data


class Transcoder(object):
  """Streaming Transcodes chunks of audio to text."""

  def __init__(self, encoding, rate, language):
    self.encoding = encoding
    self.rate = rate
    self.language = language
    self.audio = AudioStream()
    self.results = queue.Queue()

  def start(self):
    """Start up streaming speech call."""
    threading.Thread(target=self._process).start()

  def write(self, data):
    """Send chunk of audio to speech api."""
    self.audio.write(data)

  def get_result(self):
    """Gets a result from the streaming api."""
    try:
      return self.results.get(False)
    except:
      return None

  def _process(self):
    """sets up a streaming speech api request. And streams results into a queue."""
    self.client = speech_client.SpeechClient()
    self.config = cloud_speech_pb2.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=cloud_speech_pb2.RecognitionConfig(
                encoding=self.encoding,
                sample_rate_hertz=self.rate,
                language_code=self.language),
            interim_results=True)

    requests = StreamingRequest(self.audio, self.config)
    streaming_resp = self.client.streaming_recognize(iter(requests))

    # This will block until self.audio is closed...which closes the streaming_recognize req
    for resp in streaming_resp:
      self.results.put(resp)


async def audioin(websocket, path):

  # First message should be config
  config = await websocket.recv()
  if not isinstance(config, str):
    print("ERROR, no config")
    await websocket.send(
                    json.dumps({"error": "configuration not received as first message"})
                );
    return;

  config = json.loads(config)
  transcoder = Transcoder(
      encoding=config["format"],
      rate=config["rate"],
      language=config["language"],
  )

  # Start the transcoding
  transcoder.start()

  # Process incoming audio packets
  while True:
    data = await websocket.recv()
    transcoder.write(data)

    # Check for messages
    result = transcoder.get_result()
    result_dict = results_to_dict(result)
    result_json = json.dumps(result_dict)
    if result_dict  != []:
      if result_dict[0]['is_final']:
        print(result_dict)
        res = result_dict[0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
        res = get_BERT_embed(res)
        print(res)
    await websocket.send(result_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    async def main():
        server = await websockets.serve(audioin, "0.0.0.0", 80)
        await server.wait_closed()

    asyncio.run(main())
```

I never had the problem with the old client.js. it didn't raise audio time error, and STT was quite fast. I have no idea how to speed up the STT with current client.js, and audio timeout error...